# Broken executable when compiling with external build of gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, cross-compiling

I have a very simple test program `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::string A = "blah";
    std::string B = "bluh";
    return A==B;
}
```

I can build and run this fine on my Centos machine:

```
> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

> g++ foo.cpp -o foo
> ./foo
```

Now, for reasons I won't get into, I am trying to build code using a separate copy of gcc 4.4.0 residing on a network folder. That gcc was built (quite some time ago) by someone else with the intention of it being used on Centos machines, and on the whole that has worked fine in many circumstances. Unfortunately in this case it produces broken code:

```
> export PATH=/a/network/drive/gcc44/bin:$PATH
> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.0
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

> g++ foo.cpp -o foo
> ./foo
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

gdb gives the following trace:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000600f30 in memcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5 ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000600f30 in memcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5 ()
#1  0x00000000004009d0 in std::char_traits<char>::compare(char const*, char const*, unsigned long) ()
#2  0x0000000000400a3d in __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#3  0x000000000040092c in main ()
```

I tried modifying my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add `/a/network/drive/gcc44/lib`, and then it loads libgcc_s.so.1 and libstdc++.so.6 from there instead - but the result is the same. Adding those library paths at compile time also makes no difference.

If I replace the last line of code with `return A.compare(B);`, there is no segmentation fault.

I am expecting most answers to read "stop trying to do something so dumb" but the circumstances are largely beyond my control. I need to at least try to make this work, and if it is never going to work then I really want to understand what exactly is going wrong here. I suppose the remote copy of gcc is picking up some header file that is not valid for the copy of libc on my host, or something of that sort, but I am struggling to pin it down. Can anyone help me unpick this a bit more?

**EDIT**

Let me clarify the libstdc++ libraries being found at compile-time and run-time.

To figure out the compile-time library being found, I used `g++ -v` and then searched all the `-L` paths, in order, for `libstdc++.so` (let me know if that sounds wrong).

**Compile-time: local g++**

- finds `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libstdc++.so.6`
- ...which is `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.13`

**Compile-time: remote g++**

- finds `/a/network/drive/gcc44/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.0/../../../../lib64/libstdc++.so`
- ...which is `/a/network/drive/gcc44/lib64/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.11`

**Run-time**

With `/a/network/drive/gcc44/lib64` on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
> ldd foo
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff725ff000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /a/network/drive/gcc44/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9a0f3f3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003955200000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /a/network/drive/gcc44/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9a0f1dc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003954600000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003953e00000)
```

*Without* `/a/network/drive/gcc44/lib64` on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
> ldd foo
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2ddff000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000032c1e00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003955200000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000032c3600000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003954600000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003953e00000)
```

At run-time, **it makes no difference** which `libstdc++` I use: the program built with the local g++ works in both cases, and the program built with the remove g++ seg faults in both cases.

**EDIT 2**

On further digging... adding `-O3` eliminates the problem, and so does `-B /usr/bin` (ie using the linker from my host). Using the remote 4.4.0 linker, the address of memcmp is mapped to totally the wrong offset - it's in the data section of the executable. Maybe there is an obscure bug/issue with that gcc version or with the way it was compiled...

Comment: Start from preprocessing your source file using `g++ -E` and manually inspecting the output for the spurious includes. This will allow to confirm/rule out your current theory.

Comment: @oakad: `g++ -E` (or `g++ -M`) produce a lot of output. There's a mixture of local host includes (look the same in each case) and includes from the gcc folder (different path in the two cases obviously). I can't see anything that looks "spurious" to me but I don't really know what I am looking for...

Comment: GCC 4.4 is quite old. Current GCC is 4.8.2. And the `libstdc++` is compiler specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I would use a later gcc if I could. Can you expand on your other comment at all? I tried using the remote `libstdc++` at compile time, or run time, or both - always the same result.

Comment: You need to understand which `libstdc++` is used (perhaps with `ldd foo`, and by compiling with `g++ -v`).

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch - added lots of detail on the question... I am none the wiser, particularly because it doesn't seem to matter which one I use at run time